# floating point value can not be converted to UInt32 because it is greater than UInt32.max getting in swift

Tags: ios, swift

floating point value can not be converted to UInt32 because it is greater than UInt32.max
 getting this exception while

var timeSec = UInt32(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)

Comment: The error message is very clear. What is your question? (Note that there is another integer data type which is capable of holding larger values.)

Answer (score 2):

The range for `UInt32` is not large enough for your variable. You can test this in a Playground. The constant `UINT32_MAX` is *4294967295*, much smaller than your value. Use `UInt64`:

```
var timeSec = UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Comment: i have used that but i need UINT32 only because arc4random_uniform only takes uiint32 arguments